# DRY up htmlCollection to Array calls

Tags: javascript, arrays, dry, htmlcollection

I have a function that is currently using the `.getElementBy...` DOM calls in JavaScript.

```
var $ = function (selector) {
  var elements = [];

  var lastSelector  = selector.substring(selector.search(/[^#.]+$/), selector.length);

  if(selector.includes('#') !== true || selector.includes('.') !== true) {
    elements.push(document.getElementsByTagName(lastSelector));
    elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[0]);
  }

return elements;
};
```

There are a number of other if statements in the function using the code:

```
elements.push(document.getElementsByTagName(lastSelector));
elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[0]);
```

or

```
elements.push(document.getElementsByClassName(lastSelector));
elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[0]);
```

Ideally i'd like to DRY up the repeated:

```
elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[0]);
```

but I cannot define it before the `if` statements because elements has not yet been populated. It therefore tries to run the code on an empty array and errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One idea is you can store the "Array.prototype.slice.call" function in a smaller namespace, like "callElm=Array.prototype.slice.call" and then "callElm(element[0])". Other than that, why don't you convert it to a function?

Comment: `return Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[0]);`?

Comment: @haim770 it also makes use of getElementsById which doesn't push a htmlCollection, therefore throwing an error at slice. 
Sorry that wasn't clear, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly consider @marat-tanalin answer. In the case where using `querySelectorAll()` is not an option, the following worked for me, thanks @master565 for the help:

To start, wrapping the lines:

```
elements.push(document.getElementsByTagName(lastSelector));
elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[0]);
```

in a function:

```
function pushByTag(selector) {
  elements.push(document.getElementsByTagName(selector));
  elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[0]);
}
```

Dried things up considerably. Then setting a variable for the `if` argument helped a lot:

```
if(selector.includes('#') !== true || selector.includes('.') !== true)
```

became:

```
var noClassOrId = selector.includes('#') !== true || selector.includes('.') !== true;
```

Both these refactors allowed me to single line my `if` statement in to something I'd argue was fairly readable:

```
if (noClassOrId) pushByTag(lastSelector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a home-brew limited function for selecting elements by a selector, you could just use the standard [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll) available in all browsers including IE8+.

As for converting an array-like object (e. g. a DOM collection) to a real `Array` (what `Array.prototype.slice.call()` is used for in your code), I use the following function:

```js
var arrayFrom = function(arrayLike) {
    if (Array.from) {
        return Array.from(arrayLike);
    }

    var items;

    try {
        items = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike, 0);
    }
    catch(e) {
        items = [];

        var count = arrayLike.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            items.push(arrayLike[i]);
        }
    }

    return items;
};
```

or its following simplified version if browsers not supporting passing a non-`Array` argument to `Array.prototype.slice.call()` (IE8- if I recall correctly) don’t matter:

```js
var arrayFrom = function(arrayLike) {
    return Array.from
         ? Array.from(arrayLike);
         : Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike, 0);
};
```